# How to set up event tracking in Intercom through Google Tag Manager

Tags: android, ios, google-tag-manager, event-tracking, intercom

In our project we are already using **Google Tag Manager** for Google Analytic's, with that now we have to send events to **Intercom** also, How to set up event tracking in Intercom using Google Tag Manager instead of writing code in Project,Anyone have experience doing this with Intercom, can some one guide me in this

Note :: **am Using GTM Mobile container Android v4**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.** Define the function call tag in the GTM web interface with arguments as you required based on the Triggers  please find attached images for function call tag Configuration

[image] 
[image]

**2.** In Your Project Code Create a class IntercomActionEventsFunctionTagHandler which will implements FunctionCallTagCallback
    
        `public class IntercomActionEventsFunctionTagHandler implements Container.FunctionCallTagCallback {
            @Override
            public void execute(final String functionName, final Map eventDataMap) {
            }
        }`

**3.** Register Your FunctionCallTagCallBack  On load of the ContainerHolder
          `containerHolder.getContainer().registerFunctionCallTagCallback("ActionEventsFunction", new IntercomActionEventsFunctionTagHandler());`

**4.** When Ever Event Get triggered Then automatically your HandlerCode will get Triggers then finally inside execute method Log Your KeyPairs map to the Intercom
    
        `Intercom.client().logEvent("ActionEvents", eventDataMap);`

**5.** Your Final class will be like as follows
    
        `public class IntercomActionEventsFunctionTagHandler implements Container.FunctionCallTagCallback {
            @Override
            public void execute(final String functionName, final Map eventDataMap) {
                Intercom.client().logEvent("ActionEvents", eventDataMap);
            }
        }`

**6.** Don't forgot to create a version or publish GTM Configuration changes in web interface

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Custom HTML tags option under the `Tags` side menu and write Javascript code to send events to Intercom. This [blog](https://www.thyngster.com/tips-for-when-working-with-customhtmlcustom-javascript-tags-in-google-tag-manager/) post might be of help

Comment: My mistake that i have not specified, am trying it for Mobile container GTM version 4, the reference blog is for web container